# Как правильно настроить SEO/SiteMap?

Tags: seo

У меня имеется сайт и там есть динамический роутер. То есть, site.ru/video/123.
123 - это наш айди, он берется не из моей базы, а просто отправляется запрос на другой сайт.

Я имею ввиду, вот если, скажем, написать в Гугле какой-то фильм/сериал, то у вас будет «Кинопоиск» и там у них каждый фильм, каждый сериал забит в sitemap, а как быть в моем случае? У меня ведь данные хранятся не в моей базе и я, по факту, не могу собрать sitemap, ведь базы нет, а все данные берутся из другого сайта.

Я хочу, чтобы когда я написал, скажем, фильм какой-то, то у меня он находил в Гугле, как у Кинопоиска

Answer (score 0):

sitemap - это список страниц сайта. Ему абсолютно всё равно как сайт работает, как генерируется страрицы и откуда берёт данные.

[Матчасть](https://www.sitemaps.org/ru/index.html)

Comment: Правильно, но этот список страниц нужно ведь занести. Браузер попросту не знает какие у тебя url вообще существуют

Comment: Если скажем взять ВК, то к них ведь тоже как-то это сео настроена

Comment: @Jony, к чему этот твой поток сознания? Я ответил на твой вопрос. А ты изучай мастчасть.

Comment: Где ты ответил на вопрос? Это тоже самое если ты спросишь «как сделать зажигалку», а я тебе отвечу «зажигалка - это огонь»